# Creating PKGBUILD from deb for a binary

Tags: arch-linux

I converted a .deb package to PKGBUILD for a program that comes without sources. Problem is that this binary looks for some shared libraries available on Ubuntu 16.10 that have different paths on Arch. This is a part of output when I run `ldd` on the binary:

```
    libcurl-nss.so.4 => not found
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f460d645000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.61.0 => not found
    libboost_system.so.1.61.0 => not found
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.61.0 => not found
    libboost_program_options.so.1.61.0 => not found
    libxalan-c.so.111 => not found
```

What is the best way to tell this program where to find libraries on Arch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in the same directory. But some of them *do not exist* on Arch – or at least not the exact .soname that your program needs.

Boost is one problem. In Arch it is already at version 1.64, and unfortunately it does not have any ABI stability – in other words, programs using Boost must be recompiled for every version. (That's the reason numbers after the ".so" change.)

So first you'd need to make a package for Boost 1.61, in a similar manner to various existing "old version" packages (like glew1.10 for example). It'd have only the .so files but none of the other stuff, so that it could be installed side by side with latest version.

(And no, you cannot simply symlink or rename a different version – the .soname changes for a reason.)

Although cURL has no such problems with versioning (it has been at .so.4 for a long time), it has three *variants* – Arch only provides the OpenSSL and GnuTLS ones. So again you'd need to make a package which compiles cURL against the NSS library in order to get libcurl-nss. You can use the "curl-gnutls" package as base.

The last library, xalan-c, is simply not installed on your system.